# Datagridview Cell Value based on Another Cell Value

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I had this problem in a datagridview row where i have 3 columns. Datagridview data is loaded from query in vb.net. Below is the scenario:

```
Column1    Column2    Column3
  3           75         3
  3           76         3
  3           IP         0
  3          NFE         0
```

If "Column2" cells contains "IP" or "NFE", "Column3" value is "0" BUT
If "Column2" cells contains "75" or "76", "Column3" value is "EQUAL" to "Column1"

I got this code where i used "For Each" loop;

```
 Private Sub DGVGRADES_CellValueChanged(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DGVGRADES.CellValueChanged
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DGVGRADES.Rows
        If row.Cells(4).Value >= 75 Then
            row.Cells(0).Value = row.Cells(3).Value
        ElseIf row.Cells(4).Value.ToString <= 3 Then
            row.Cells(0).Value = row.Cells(3).Value
        ElseIf row.Cells(4).Value < 75 Then
            row.Cells(0).Value = 0
        ElseIf row.Cells(4).Value = "IP" Then
            row.Cells(0).Value = 0
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

BUT sad to note that returns me this ERROR;

```
 "Conversion from string "IP" to type 'Double' is not valid."
```

Please help me with this problem thank you.

Comment: It looks like there's an error in your string construction and that the substitution of `@LabSubject` failed.

Comment: The issue is your insert. Instead of passing it the values you are literally passing it the dynamic sql for each of your variables.

Comment: Can anybody help me with this problem.?

Comment: Can anybody help me with this problem? Please?